# Sqlalchemy: session.query() vs conn.execute()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have found that each session call `.rollback()` when closed.

So dose it meen that for best performance, if i need just single select (no transaction needed) than it is better to rewrite code from

```
session = init_session()
result = session.query(Currency.id, Currency.code).all()
session.close()
```

to version with `conn.execute()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to Python's [DB-API 2.0 spec](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) you will be running everything in a transaction, even if you use the [emulated "autocommit" feature](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#library-level-e-g-emulated-autocommit) of SQLAlchemy, unless you explicitly opt to [setting the transaction isolation level](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-including-dbapi-autocommit) to `"AUTOCOMMIT"` and your driver supports it. From a performance perspective running your query in a transaction should have negligible impact. Just remember to close the transaction when you are done, which you seem to be doing, so that any reserved resources are freed.